# Cakephp 2.4.5 Default Controller not loading

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.4

I am new in cakephp trying to loading default controller as Pages

This is my route :

> Router::redirect ('/', array('controller' => 'pages', 'action' => 'display'));
>
> Router::connect('/pages/**', array('controller' => 'pages', 'action' => 'display'));

When I run **"http://localhost/project/index.php"** then its working fine but try with **"http://localhost/project/"** its not loading default controller (Pages)

Without htaccess & with htaccess its giving same issue.

This is error:

> Controller class ProjectController could not be found.

Error:

> The requested address '/project/index.php/project/' was not found on
>   this server.

Comment: Did you changed `.htaccess` file

Comment: Yes I tested with htaccess and without htaccess but didn't run default on root "/"

Comment: this is my htaccess (webroot): 
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>

Comment: Its not the same that which come with cakephp

Comment: .htaccess isn't issue I have added default htaccess but didn't run.

Comment: What are you actually trying to do here? Are you trying to show a page (.ctp file in the folder "View/Pages") or are you trying to show a view from a controller? As you're writing in your Routes you connect every /pages/* to the Pages controller with the display action. So if you want to show the project view (.ctp) you have to navigate to /pages/project. If you're having issues with .htaccess or url rewriting in general take a look at: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/installation/url-rewriting.html.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its resolved

Added baseUrl in app controller:

```
function beforeRender(){
  $this->set('baseUrl', 'http://'.$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].Router::url('/'));
}
```

Removed App.baseUrl from Core.php :

```
Configure::write('App.baseUrl', env('SCRIPT_NAME'));
```

now its working fine on:
    http://localhost/app/

Answer (score 0):

You are running in subdirectory, so you should set RewriteBase:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c> 
    RewriteEngine On 
    RewriteBase /project/
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /project/index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L] 
</IfModule
```

Answer (score 0):

As per cakephp manual :

http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/development/routing.html#redirect-routing

You should try

```
Router::scope('/', function ($routes) {
$routes->redirect(
    '/home/*',
    ['controller' => 'Articles', 'action' => 'view'],
    ['persist' => true]
    // Or ['persist'=>['id']] for default routing where the
    // view action expects $id as an argument.
);
})
```

Instead of Router::redirect.You should try this method once, might issue got resolved.

Comment: Oh !! I didn't focused there !! Meanwhile, Above answer might not affect of versions. I don't know much about that.